# How can you run a script while keeping the window minimized using VBScript?

Tags: vbscript

I have scripted automatic key presses to retrieve information from a form in MS Access, however the script opens the Access window and keeps it open while I continue to pull information from it...

so my question is, how can I run this script that uses key presses ( .sendkeys ) even if the window was minimized?

```
WshShell.Run "C:\Users\ashleyl\Desktop\AquaProd.lnk"

WshShell.SendKeys "{LEFT}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
WshShell.SendKeys "^{f}"
WshShell.SendKeys patch
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{UP}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"

WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WshShell.SendKeys "^{c}"
WshShell.Sendkeys "^{TAB}"
WshShell.Sendkeys "^{TAB}"
WshShell.Sendkeys "{TAB}"
```

This is just an example of some of the key presses.

Comment: As far as I know, `Sendkeys` method does not send key strokes to a precise window, it sends key strokes to the active window.

Comment: You should use something like [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) or you can pull the info from Access directly using ADO